# How to run Great Expectations expectations on multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, validation, great-expectations

I want to use the [Great Expectations testing suite](https://great-expectations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to run the same validations on many columns. I see that there's a closed [feature request](https://github.com/great-expectations/great_expectations/issues/1316) to have this as a built-in expectation, but can this be done with a for-loop over the column names?

In addition, I need to filter which columns to test-- I am training various computer vision models on different classes ids, so I need to select all columns corresponding to class ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you search the docs for `filter()` there isn't anything documented, but if you check `type(batch)` you see that it's a `great_expectations.dataset.pandas_dataset.PandasDataset`, which [according to the docs](https://docs.greatexpectations.io/en/latest/autoapi/great_expectations/dataset/pandas_dataset/index.html#great_expectations.dataset.pandas_dataset.PandasDataset) subclasses `pandas.DataFrame`.

So, you can filter columns as you would a regular dataframe using `batch.filter()` and run a for loop on the columns:

[image: Expectations on filtered columns]

There's a gotcha, though: you can't run the expectations directly on the filtered DataFrame; instead, you have to run the expectations on the original `batch` dataset, or else you will get errors when you try to do `filtered_df.save_expectation_suite()`

[image: Expectation results]